# Rounded corners with background image for text view in android studio

Tags: android, image, textview, shapes, xml-drawable

I have a text view and and  I want its background to be a image and also its corners rounded. I have tried that by creating a drawable file but the background image gets spilled out.

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <TextView
    
android:id="@+id/info_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:background="@drawable/drawable_file"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

drawable_file.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/img" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <shape>
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp" />
           
            <corners android:radius="50dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

[Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9esq.jpg)

[Example Output:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5LXYK.png)

Comment: Can you please show an example output you need

Comment: I have added the example output.

Answer (score 0):

As in official Android documentation for [LayerList](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList)

> A LayerDrawable is a drawable object that manages an array of other drawables. Each drawable in the list is drawn in the order of the list—the last drawable in the list is drawn on top.

Meaning your drawable needs to be placed after the rounded background to be visible.

Comment: If I place drawable image item after the rounded background, then it is overlapping the rounded corners and displaying the whole image.